# Qual a principal diferença entre Kafk, RabbitMQ e Digibee?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, rabbitmq, apache-kafka

Estou trabalhando em projeto de médio porte, e cheguei em um momento
que preciso utilizar um sistema de mensageria para realizar o envio
de informações para um sistema de terceiros.

Não gostaria de utilizar um canhão pra matar uma mosca, e gostaria de
opiniões para ter uma base melhor.

Qual sistema seria mais apropriado para realizar uma média de 12 mil mensagens/mês,
fazendo a utilização de retry, ack, deadletter...

Kafk, RabbitMQ, Digibee?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Bom Dia,

Tudo bem?

Nesse caso, eu iria de RabbitMQ, ele já tem nativamente várias features que atendem o seu projeto (retry, ack, deadletter) e não requer tanto esforço de implementação quanto um Kafka precisa. Fora que ele atende praticamente todos os patterns de integração.

A infra é bem gerenciável,você consegue subir os containers bem fácil, tem uma boa interface e dá conta de sobra nesse volume.

Abraços

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Caio.